# Can present perfect replace past perfect?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

First sentence:

> Biden also *said* **he had told** the Israelis to stop "intercommunal
> fighting" in the flashpoint city of Jerusalem.

I have read [present-perfect-vs-past-perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245318/present-perfect-vs-past-perfect), but still have no clue. I'm wondering if I can replace **he had told** with **he has told**. What I know, both are representing an event in the past that has done/had done.

Another sentence:

> Canada **has extended** its ban on passenger flights from India and
> Pakistan by 30 days to Jun 21 as part of a campaign to fight COVID-19,
> Transport Minister Omar Alghabra *said* on Friday (May 21).

My first guess of the first sentence is it's a reported speech since there's "said" as past simple and using past perfect, I can agree with that. However, comparing to the second sentence with the same topic (reported speech), but it's using **has**? So, what's the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the answer: it's because it's reported speech.

> Biden said, "I have told the Israelis to stop "intercommunal fighting".

means the same as

> Biden said he had told the Israelis to stop "intercommunal fighting.

In the second example, Canada's *action* is reported, not their speech, so it would be incorrect to use past perfect.